# Отсортировать элементы массива по алфавиту C++

Tags: c++, c, массивы, сортировка

Всем привет! Необходимо отсортировать массив по алфавиту. В моем случае это W количество элементов в массиве FZ. Будет интересно почитать ваши идеи, заранее большое спасибо!

Код если он тут нужен :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
cout << "How much arr elem?\n";
int W; //Обьявили переменную W. Количество элементов массива.
cin >> W;
char FZ[W];

for(int i=0;i<W;i++)                // Цикл ввода элемента массива с клавиатуры.
{
    cout << "enter array elem\n";
    cin >> FZ[i];
}

for(int i=0;i<W;i++)                // Цикл вывода элементов массива.
{
    cout << FZ[i] << " "
}
}
```

Comment: Эээ... Вам точно надо сортировать массив целых **чисел** по **алфавиту**?...

Comment: нужно отсортировать буквы, я только учусь поэтому есть некоторые проблемы , если есть время мне обьяснить как переставить все на буквы буду вам благодарен.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как оказалось символы ( ну или проще буквы английского алфавита) можно сравнивать.
Это значит, что `a < b` ,а `b < c`.
Исходя из этого фигачим все пузырьком (см. Пузырьковая сортировка).

Код в итоге получился во такой! И он рабочий

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{

    cout << "How much arr elem?\n";
    int W; //Обьявили переменную W. Количество элементов массива.
    cin >> W;
    char FZ[W];
    
    for(int i=0;i<W;i++)                // Цикл ввода элемента массива с клавиатуры.
    {
        cout << "enter array elem\n";
        cin >> FZ[i];
    }
    cout << "\nnotSort array:" << " ";
    for(int i=0;i<W;i++)                // Цикл вывода элементов массива.
    {
        cout << FZ[i] << " ";
    }
    
    // Пошла СОРТИРОВКА оп оп оп
    
    
    for (int i = 0; i < W; i++)
    {
      for (int j = 0; j < W-1; j++)
      {
        if (FZ[j] > FZ[j + 1])
        {
          int b = FZ[j]; // создали дополнительную переменную
          FZ[j] = FZ[j + 1]; // меняем местами
          FZ[j + 1] = b; // значения элементов
        }
      }
    }
    cout << "\nSort array:" << " ";
 
    for (int i = 0; i < W; i++) {
    cout << FZ[i] << " "; // выводим элементы массива
    }
}
```

Результат:

```
How much arr elem?
4
enter array elem
a
enter array elem
g
enter array elem
c
enter array elem
f

notSort array: a g c f 
Sort array: a c f g
```

Comment: `Никто не поможет, надо самому разбираться.` можно так подумать, что вы многим помогли.

Comment: Молодец! А еще можно посмотреть [man qsort](https://linux.die.net/man/3/qsort) (приоткроете дверь в пока еще новый  для вас мир)

Comment: @nazarpunk, представьте себе - можно!

Comment: @avp, cпасибо большое!!!